# Cannot create table with unicode characters in the name

Tags: mysql

I create a table in 【Navicate for MySQL】，but can't complete it.

this is my code.

```
CREATE table `成绩表`(
`学号` char(10),
`课号` char(10),
`成绩` int,
PRIMARY KEY(`学号`, `课号`)
)

error:
[SQL] CREATE table `成绩表`(
`学号` char(10),
`课号` char(10),
`成绩` int,
PRIMARY KEY(`学号`, `课号`)
)

[Err] 1005 - Can't create table '成绩表' (errno: 22)
```

Comment: Are those characters part of the unicode basic multilingual plane? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html

Comment: _ASCII NUL (U+0000) and supplementary characters (U+10000 and higher) are not permitted in quoted or unquoted identifiers._ From the doc link above...

Comment: Please post the version(版本号) of your MySQL

Comment: @Michael: That's good thinking, but those characters are all in the BMP. So unless some sort of normalization is preventing us from seeing the original non-BMP characters, that's not the problem.

Comment: Does it work if you try creating it without the primary key?

Comment: That works for me when I paste it into MySQL Workbench and run it (though it does not display correctly in the font used and all the column/table names just show up as boxes)

Comment: I'd say MySQL is simply not able to handle these characters as part of a table or column name. You need to use different characters (preferably ASCII only...)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name according to MySQL manual (V 5.5x) it is able to handle unicode from U+0001 up to U+FFFF for table and column names .

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html) it is able to handle unicode from U+0001 up to U+FFFF for table and column names - so the reason for you see most likely will need some digging:

The error message says `errno` is `22` which IIRC translates into the OS error code for `invalid argument`. That in turn means that somewhere along the way deep inside MySQL itself there is some function called with an argument that it can't accept.

I would suspect that the function called is from the C runtime and/or OS and that it is most likely filesystem related.

That in turn means it is either a bug or some obscure behaviour of MySQL interacting with the OS/filesystem/setup you are using...

I would recommend to definitely contact MySQL/Oracle about this since that is IMHO far beyond what SO can handle...